# Finding the Lipschitz limit.

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

$\mathbf{C}$ is a set consisting of the convergent sequences in $\mathbb{R}$. If $a=(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ and $b=(b_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ are elements of $\mathbf{C}$ we have:

$d_{\infty}(a,b) = \sup \{ |a_n-b_n| : n\in\mathbb{N} \}$

How do I check that the map from $\mathbf{C}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ which to a converging sequence associates its limit is 1-Lipschitz?

Comment: Which norm do you put on $\textbf{C}$ ?

Comment: What norm are you considering on $\mathbf C$?

Comment: Oh, sorry. It was supposed to be $\mathbf{C}$ consists of the convergent sequences as well. The norm: if a=$(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ and b=$(b_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}. d_{\infty}(a,b) = \sup\{|a_n-b_n| : n\in\mathbb{N} \}$

Comment: Add this in the question, please.